# Using an opaque ID type in place of primitive.ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

In a `db` package, I don't want to expose MongoDB's `primitive.ObjectID` type as part of its public API. Instead, I want to define `type Id interface{}` within the `db` package and expose that. Since the driver doesn't know how to transform the database's ObjectID type into my custom ID type, I registered a type decoder like so:

```golang
type Id interface{}

var idType = reflect.TypeOf((*Id)(nil)).Elem()

type User struct {
    Id `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    reg := bson.NewRegistryBuilder().
        RegisterTypeDecoder(idType, bsoncodec.ValueDecoderFunc(idDecodeValue)).
        Build()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), options.Client().
        ApplyURI("...").
        SetRegistry(reg))
    coll := client.Database("...").Collection("...")

    var u0 User
    coll.InsertOne(context.TODO(), u0)

    var u1 User
    coll.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.D{}).Decode(&u1)
}

func idDecodeValue(dc bsoncodec.DecodeContext, vr bsonrw.ValueReader, val reflect.Value) error {
    if !val.IsValid() || val.Type() != idType {
        return bsoncodec.ValueDecoderError{
            Name:     "IdDecodeValue",
            Types:    []reflect.Type{idType},
            Received: val,
        }
    }
    oid, _ := vr.ReadObjectID()
    val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(oid))
    return nil
}
```

I saw that there exists a `bsoncodec.NewEmptyInterfaceCodec()` to use in place of `idDecodeValue`, but that only seems to work when `User.Id`'s type is exactly `interface{}`. I wrote `idDecodeValue` based off of the existing codecs, but I'm not entirely sure what's going on (mostly due to not knowing when `val.IsValid()` would ever return false). Is all of this the best, most idiomatic way to go about supporting a custom ID type?

Comment: I have the exact same problem trying to implement generic ID interface support for EventHorizon (https://github.com/looplab/eventhorizon/issues/28). Would be interested in any progress on this.

Comment: You could try to implement a HookEncoder instead. I'm going down that path but I have run into another problem with the reflection of types based on primitive types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938572/get-the-reflect-kind-of-a-type-which-is-based-on-a-primitive-type