# Get the reflect.Kind of a type which is based on a primitive type

Tags: go, reflection, interface

I would like to get the reflect.Kind as a reflect.Interface for a type which implements an interface but where its implementation is based on a primitive type: `type id string`

An alternative answer for this could be how to get any kind of reflect.Type that returns reflect.Interfaces when calling Kind().

Here is a full example on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Sdudg7BjrTN):

```
type ID interface {
    myid()
}

type id string

func (id) myid() {}

func main() {
    id := ID(id("test"))
    
    fmt.Println(id)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(id))
    
    // How to get the kind to return "reflect.Interface" from the var "id"?
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(id).Kind())
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) (and [`reflect.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf)) expects an `interface{}`. Basically whatever value you pass to `reflect.TypeOf()`, if it's not already an interface value, it will be wrapped in an `interface{}` implicitly. If the passed value is already an interface value, then the concrete value stored in it will be passed as a `interface{}`.

In order to avoid this "repacking", this is one of those rare cases when a pointer to interface makes sense, in fact you can't avoid it here. You have to pass a pointer to the interface value.

So if you pass a pointer to interface, this pointer will be wrapped in an `interface{}` value. You may use `Type.Elem()` to get the type descriptor of the "pointed type": that is, the element type of the pointer type, which will be the type descriptor of the interface type you're looking for.

Example:

```
id := ID(id("test"))

fmt.Println(id)
t := reflect.TypeOf(&id).Elem()
fmt.Println(t)

fmt.Println(t.Kind())
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Qf7_FWJ2AxZ)):

```
test
main.ID
interface
```

See related question: [What is the difference between reflect.ValueOf() and Value.Elem() in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388657/what-is-the-difference-between-reflect-valueof-and-value-elem-in-go/57388715#57388715)

Comment: Awesome, I also happened to experiment my way to the same answer. But you have given a really great background to how it works! Thanks!