# what does reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()` mean?

Tags: go, go-reflect

```
func (s *service) registerMethods() {
    s.method = make(map[string]*methodType)
    for i := 0; i < s.typ.NumMethod(); i++ {
        method := s.typ.Method(i)
        mType := method.Type
        if mType.NumIn() != 3 || mType.NumOut() != 1 {
            continue
        }
        if mType.Out(0) != reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem() {
            continue
        }
        argType, replyType := mType.In(1), mType.In(2)
        if !isExportedOrBuiltinType(argType) || !isExportedOrBuiltinType(replyType) {
            continue
        }
        s.method[method.Name] = &methodType{
            method:    method,
            ArgType:   argType,
            ReplyType: replyType,
        }
        log.Printf("rpc server: register %s.%s\n", s.name, method.Name)
    }
}
```

what does `reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()` mean in this code? I know `if mType.Out(0) != reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()` is trying to determine if the method's return type is error not not. But for me, `reflect.TypeOf((error)(nil))` intuitively will do the same, but unfortunately not. When I try to compile this code, it says type error is not an expression, what does it mean in this context? Does not `reflect.Typeof()` accepts a argument of certain type? I found that (*error)(nil) is equivalent to *error = nil. I am confused with this expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR;** `reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()` is an expression used to obtain the [`reflect.Type`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Type) type descriptor of the interface type `error`. Using `reflect.TypeOf(error(nil))` **cannot** be used for the same purpose (read the *why* below).

---

`reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()` achieves its goal by using a typed `nil` pointer value of type `*error`, passing it to `reflect.TypeOf()` to get the `reflect.Type` descriptor of the type `*error`, and uses `Type.Elem()` to get the type descriptor of the element (base) type of `*error`, which is `error`.

[`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#TypeOf) expects an `interface{}` value:

```
func TypeOf(i interface{}) Type
```

Basically whatever value you pass to `reflect.TypeOf()`, if it's not already an interface value, it will be wrapped in an `interface{}` implicitly. If the passed value is already an interface value, then the concrete value stored in it will be passed as `interface{}`.

So if you try to pass an `error` value to it, since `error` is an interface type, the concrete value stored in it will be "repacked" into an `interface{}` value. **The interface type `error` will not be retained / transferred!**

If you pass a `nil` value of type `error`, e.g. `error(nil)`, since the interface value itself is `nil`, it contains no concrete value and type, a `nil` `interface{}` value will be passed, that will result in `nil` `reflect.Type` returned. Quoting from `reflect.TypeOf()`:

> TypeOf returns the reflection Type that represents the dynamic type of i. **If i is a nil interface value, TypeOf returns nil.**

If you pass a value of type `*error` (which may be a `nil` pointer), it's not an interface value, it's a pointer value (a pointer to interface). So it will be wrapped in an `interface{}` value, and the concrete value stored in it will be of type `*error`. Using `Type.Elem()` you can access the pointed type, that is `error`.

This is one of the rare cases when using a pointer to interface makes sense, and in fact inevitable.

See related questions:

[Get the reflect.Kind of a type which is based on a primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938572/get-the-reflect-kind-of-a-type-which-is-based-on-a-primitive-type/63938859#63938859)

[What is the difference between reflect.ValueOf() and Value.Elem() in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388657/what-is-the-difference-between-reflect-valueof-and-value-elem-in-go/57388715#57388715)

[Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here/29138676#29138676)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I am still confused that `error(nil) ` gives `nil`, `(*error)(nil) ` gives `*error`

Comment: @WeiWong There's a difference between a `nil` interface value and a non-`nil` interface value wrapping a `nil` pointer. Check out [Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here/29138676#29138676)

Comment: I read the Question you mentioned. So `error` is an interface type, `*error` is not an interface type? I get that (*error)(nil) is a pointer of error type pointing to nil, but what about  `error(nil)`? I am trying to understand why `error(nil)` gives `<nil>`

Comment: It's in my answer, please read again. Passing `(*error)(nil)` will pass a non-`nil` `interface{}` value, wrapping a `nil` `*error` pointer. Passing `error(nil)` will pass a `nil` `interface{}` value, wrapping _nothing_. A `nil` interface value holds nothing.

Comment: `error(nil)` is a `nil` value of `error interface`, `TypeOf(error(nil)) `-> `TypeOf(interface{error(nil)})`  `interface{error(nil)}` became `nil value` of `interface{}` ? I don't know if my understanding is correct. Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: If you pass `error(nil)`, `reflect.TypeOf()` will receive a `nil` interface value. Again, this is in my answer.

Comment: @WeiWong: this is one of those cases where Go just isn't quite that simple: `error` is itself an interface type, so that `error(nil)` turns into the <nil,nil> pair at compile time. Other non-interface types don't have this issue, e.g., `type T = *int` makes `T` an alias for `*int`, so `T(nil)` turns into `<*int,nil>` (https://play.golang.org/p/XO1vjwk031U). It's critical to think of Go in terms of <type,value> pairs at all times.

Comment: @torek `(*int)(nil)`turns into`<*int, nil>` looks intuitive to me.  `interface{}(nil)` turns into `<nil, nil>` does not. `<?, nil>` the value part turns into nil makes sense.  `nil` is `<type:nil, value:nil>` when `interface{}(nil)` applies, interface is abstract type, so it turns to <type:nil, value:nil> ? Is that how should I understand it?

Comment: More or less, yes. All interface *values* have a <type,value> pair at runtime. The type in the <type,value> pair is supplied by the compiler. When the compiler doesn't have a pre-provided type, the compiler provides `nil` instead. So any uninitialized variable of type `interface I`, for any `I`, is `<nil,nil>`. The Go authors then chose (for whatever reason) to say that, for any interface *value* v, `v==nil` is true if and only if `v` holds `<nil,nil>`. That leads to `error(nil)` "wanting" to be `<nil,nil>` rather than `<error,nil>`.

Comment: If the Go authors had chosen that, at runtime, the `v==nil` test should test only the *value* part of `v`, not the type part, `error(nil)` could reasonably be the `<error,nil>` pair. That would be a different language, with other behaviors also being different; whether it would be better, worse, or equivalent is a matter of taste.

Comment: @torek Thank you. You should probably post this comment in Answer. It's really useful!

Comment: @torek If I want to determine if  a method's return type is error interface or not. Is this the only way `if method.Out(0) != reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()`?  `if method.Out(0) != reflect.TypeOf(error)` why doesn't this code compile? `func TypeOf(i interface{}) Type` error is an interface, it should have work. [link](https://play.golang.org/p/u2UV3pGUzra)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236265/discussion-between-wei-wong-and-torek).

Comment: The argument to `reflect.TypeOf` has to be a *value* (of type `interface{}`); `error` is a *type* (of type `interface { ... }` where the `...` part is filled in). Other languages sometimes work around this distinction between "type" and "value" by decreeing that types *are* values (which leads to a different problem), but Go doesn't do that.

Comment: @torek  Is there any other workaround for this expression `if method.Out(0) != reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()` ?   It looks ugly and unnatural. I took a weekend to figure it out. I wouldn't be able to write code like this to achieve my goal if I am about to write code on my own next time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "workaround". That's the *shortest* way to write the expression, given what you've started with. It's not clear what your real goal is though—if your goal is to work with `reflect`, you've done that, and have achieved the minimal set of things to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

With [Go 1.22](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.22#compiler) (Q4 2023), this will be

```
reflect.TypeFor[error]()
```

See [`golang/go` issue 60088](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60088)

> ### reflect: add `TypeFor`
>
> `reflect.TypeOf` is one of a few fundamental reflect APIs. It returns the dynamic type of a value. This is, strictly speaking, sufficient.
>
> However, it is non-obvious how to use it to get a static type. The correct code is long, awkward, and hard to explain.
>
> Pre-generics, there was no way to write a nice API to get a static `reflect.Type`. Now there is:
>
> ```golang
> // MakeType returns the reflection Type that represents the static type of T.
> func MakeType[T any]() reflect.Type {
>   return reflect.TypeOf((*T)(nil)).Elem()
> }
> ```
>
> I propose that we add it.

This is done with [CL 513478](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/513478), and [commit 42d2dfb](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/42d2dfb4305aecb3a6e5494db6b8f6e48a09b420#diff-afde94a29f48cf21e5195779a44c1cde45d67d52f398e86a93e0c317faffb113).

Example: [`src/encoding/json/encode.go`](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/514655/2/src/encoding/json/encode.go), or [src/html/template/content.go](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/514640/2/src/html/template/content.go).

Instead of:

```golang
var (
    marshalerType     = reflect.TypeOf((*Marshaler)(nil)).Elem()
    textMarshalerType = reflect.TypeOf((*encoding.TextMarshaler)(nil)).Elem()

    errorType       = reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()
    fmtStringerType = reflect.TypeOf((*fmt.Stringer)(nil)).Elem()
)
```

You now have:

```golang
var (
    marshalerType     = reflect.TypeFor[Marshaler]()
    textMarshalerType = reflect.TypeFor[encoding.TextMarshaler]()

    errorType       = reflect.TypeFor[error]()
    fmtStringerType = reflect.TypeFor[fmt.Stringer]()
)
```