# Implement a struct-to-csv writer in Go

Tags: go, reflection, interface

The following code attempt to implement a generic CSV writer for any simple struct. By "simple", I mean field value of the struct are of standard, simple types (int, string etc).

```
type (
    CSV interface {
        Header() []string
        String([]string) (string, error)
    }
    CSVArray []CSV
)


func CSVOutput(w io.Writer, data CSVArray, cols []string) error {
    if len(data) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    _, err := fmt.Fprintln(w, data[0].Header())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, d := range data {
        str, err := d.String(cols)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        _, err = fmt.Fprintln(w, str)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The problem is `CSVOutput()` does not actually work.  e.g.:

```
var data []Employee //the Employee struct implements CSV interface
CSVOutput(w, data, nil)
```

Compilation failed: `cannot use data (type []Employee) as type CSVArray in argument to CSVOutput`

I understand that []CSV is not same as []Employee, as explained [here](https://medium.com/@SaifAbid/slice-interfaces-8c78f8b6345d), and many other resources available online.

That said, is it possible to rewrite the `CSVOutput()` function by using **reflection**:

```
func CSVOutput(w io.Writer, data interfac{}, cols []string) error {
    sliceOfIntf = castToSlice(data) //how to do this?
    if !implementedCSV(sliceOfIntf[0]) { //and how to do this?
        return errors.New("not csv")
    }
    ... ...
}
```

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jszwec/csvutil#readme-marshal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to rewrite the CSVOutput() function by using reflection

Yes

```golang
// if data is []Employee{...}, then you can do the following:

rv := reflect.ValueOf(data)
if rv.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
    return fmt.Errorf("data is not slice")
}
if !rv.Type().Elem().Implements(reflect.TypeOf((*CSV)(nil)).Elem()) {
    return fmt.Errorf("slice element does not implement CSV")
}

csvArr := make(CSVArray, rv.Len())
for i := 0; i < rv.Len(); i++ {
    csvArr[i] = rv.Index(i).Interface().(CSV)
}

// now csvArr is CSVArray containing all the elements of data
```

https://go.dev/play/p/gcSOid533gx

Comment: could you explain what is `(*CSV)(nil)`? Cast nil into a CSV interface? Can we make it `CSV(nil)` ?

Comment: *"what is `(*CSV)(nil)`"* -- that's an expression that converts `nil` to `*CSV`. *"Can we make it `CSV(nil)`"* -- Nope. You need pointer-to-interface because otherwise the interface-type information would be lost.

Comment: @xrfang for a more complete explanation see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63938859/965900